# Check if file exists in subdirectory and otherwise redirect everything to main controller

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I'd like to do with `mod_rewrite` in a `.htaccess` file under Apache is the following:

- If a request for *any* file or path, e.g. `foo.txt` or `foo/bar`, is received, check if such file exists in the `public` subdirectory, e.g. `public/foo.txt` or `public/foo/bar`. It if does, just display that file.
- Otherwise

  - Redirect *everything* to the main controller `index.php`

My attempt at a solution was this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Don't rewrite requests for files in the 'public' directory
    RewriteRule ^(public)($|/) - [L]

    # For all other files first check if they exist in 'public'
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
    RewriteRule ^ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

    # Let 'index.php' handle everything else
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately, there is a major flaw: It doesn't work in subdirectories, i.e. when the `.htaccess` and all the other files are moved from `/` to `/sub/`. Ideally, it would work in *arbitrary* subfolders, of course.

Can anybody help? How can I fix the `.htaccess` to eliminate that flaw?

Comment: .htaccess only works in the current folder apache is trying to serve files from. So [1] cannot be solved, you'll need a global set of rewrite rules on you webserver configuration.

Comment: For your second problem, you don't have a condition that matches the request to /foo.txt, so your current rewrite rules will never treat those requests.

Comment: @Marcel Regarding (1), there may be a misunderstanding. But otherwise, I don't see why the `.htaccess` couldn't work when the entire site is moved into a subdirectory, e.g. `/foo/`, instead of just `/` (the root directory). If you write a simple rule such as `RewriteRule . index.php [L]`, it will also work in both cases. Just not the more complex rule set from the question.

Comment: @Marcel Regarding (2), there *is* a rule that matches these requests. It's the `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` rule that matches every request. I've changed the question to drop the second problem. It's really just the issue of root directory vs subdirectories now.

Comment: but it will only work inside a folder? so how come it will work for `/foo.txt`?

Comment: @Marcel If you put all your files, including the `.htaccess` itself, in the root (`/`), it will work just fine. Why the last rule (`RewriteRule .`) works everywhere is obvious, as it's just rewriting *any* request that arrives in the folder where our `.htaccess` is. But the two rules above do *not* work anymore if you move all your files, including the `.htaccess`, to a subfolder, such as `/foo/`. The reason is that the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` and `%{REQUEST_URI}` variables cause trouble. But I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Have you tried:

`# If file or directory exists, deliver it`
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteRule (.*) - [L]`
``
`#Otherwise redirect to php...`
`RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?q=$1 [L]`

Comment: @ajerez Thanks, but that doesn't consider the `public` directory at all. It's just the common main controller used by many frameworks. Of course, it works, but it's not really related to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem where I want to distribute a web app that behaves as you describe: there are a bunch of static files in a specific directory that can be accessed as if they are on the web-app root (i.e. trying `/images/pic.png` get the image in `public/images/pic.png`) , and everything else gets mapped to a controller script.

The first problem I encountered is that [`-f` in `RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) doesn't work with a relative path - i.e. if the "TestPattern" string can be resolved to a file relative to the directory where the condition is specified (using `.htaccess`), `-f` will still return "not matched"<sup>(1)</sup>.

So we need to try to "understand" what is the per-directory prefix that the `.htaccess` file is in, and `mod_rewrite` actually resolves this for us and makes sure that the `RewriteRule` is always evaluated relative to the per-directory prefix `.htaccess` file - but unfortunately it doesn't expose that information in anyway that `RewriteCond` can access (they really should let us have that).

That being said, apparently there are few weird things you can do with `RewriteCond` to force the "CondPattern" to tease out the relationship between `%{REQUEST_URI}` and the `RewriteRule` input - read [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062290) for all the weird things that you can achieve.

But shortening these tricks just to the problem at hand (getting `-f` to match to the correct path relative to .htaccess, regardless where it might be) we get this, rather simple, thing:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1static/%2 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  static/$1 [END]

RewriteRule . index.php [END,QSA]
```

#### Explanation:

The regular expression in the `RewriteCond` is very limited in that it isn't resolved for variables and captured text, but it can use back references to itself using the `\<number>` syntax. So we first create a string made up of:

- The original request URI
- A hard-coded delimited that we don't expect to occur in the URL (the `::` part).
- The local (per-directory) part of the URI that `RewriteRule` will match on - this is the `$1` part: `RewriteCond` can look at the capture group of the target `RewriteRule`<sup>(2)</sup>, so we capture the entire input.

We then apply a regular expression that explains the relationship between that request URI and the `RewriteRule` input - the request URI is made up of two parts (the first and second captures) where the first ends with a `/` and the second is identical to what appears after the `::` delimiter - the `\2` is just referencing the second capture in the same regexp, and saying that it must be identical.

The result is that we have broken up the request URI into two capture groups - the first one is the local per-directory prefix that `mod_rewrite` enjoys privately and the second is the local path under that directory that we want to check. The second conditions uses `%<number>` to refer to these captures building an absolute path under the document root<sup>(3)</sup>. Note that `%1` captures both the leading and trailing slashes of the prefix URI.

Finally, note that I'm using the `END` flag instead of `L` (last), as it is faster and exists `mod_rewrite` immediately. This allows me to drop the line with the `RewriteRule … - [L]` which exists just to stop the behavior of `L` that does not actually stop processing: it just goes back the beginning or the rewrite rules with the new URL. `END` is much simpler.

#### Footnotes:

1. Actually, relative path resolution does work under certain conditions, as documented in [the bug report for this problem](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64447). It just that it doesn't work as expected and in most common configurations will not work at all.
2. This weird-looking backwards behavior is actually pretty simple: Apache always first resolves the `RewriteRule` and only then check if the conditions allow it to be applied.
3. This, BTW, won't work if you use `Alias` or similar methods to map parts of the server URI space to other places not under the document root. See the documentation for `CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT` to figure out how to workaround this problem.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this detailed walkthrough, and for the references to the related question (sometimes hard to find) and the Apache issue. It’s always great to have someone else with the same problem (Sorry!)

Comment: @caw - sure, and good luck  if this answer works for you, please accept it and upvote. Thanks 

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot (and didn’t see) that there was actually no selected answer yet after all those years. As for upvoting, it’s a shame, but I’d need 2 additional reputation points to do that :(

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't seem that you want to access anything outside of the /public folder? If so, this seems easy to me, and without any rewrites (I hope there isn't any reason you actually *want* to use `mod_rewrite`!)

1. Put index.php in the public folder
2. Set the DocumentRoot to be the public folder
3. Use ErrorDocument to redirect any file not found to index.php

If you have a reason to use the public folder, then you can use `mod_rewrite` to redirect anything except index.php to public/anything, and still use ErrorDocument to redirect to index.php.

Answer (score 3):

This ruleset works for me.  I omitted the check for paths that start /public.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /public/$1 [L]

RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

If `/public` is not in you document root, you can replacing %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} with the on disk path to the /public directory.  The `CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT` may contain the file path to the content directory for the `.htaccess` file  Unless you have the same file in `/public/public` as in `/public`, the `RewriteCond` won't match.  I avoided this whole issue by using my equivalent of `/public` as my docroot.  If you can't put `index.php` in `/public`, you can use `Alias` to access it where it is.

Your approach involves rewriting all matches. An alternate ruleset using `../public` as your document root would be:

Alias /index.php /var/www/index.php
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

You could also handle the missing files with a custom 404 error page.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it does *not* work for me. Maybe someone else can test as well and verify, but on my Apache test server, these rules did only produce 404 errors (in a subdirectory) and 500 errors (in the root directory). Apart from that, the first rule (that you omitted) was important when I tried these rules because any request for `public/*` is valid already and should not be rewritten again (which would result in `public/public/*`).

Comment: @MarcoW. Updated response.

Comment: `DOCUMENT_ROOT` may be set to something not entirely correct. In my case it was `/var/www` whereas the real path should have been `/var/www/example.com/web`. This can be fixed by manually specifying the full absolute document root in RewriteCond.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `RewriteBase` when you move it to a subfolder:

```
RewriteBase /subfolder/
# Rules
```

Comment: Thanks! I wish that worked, but it doesn't. That was the first thing I tried. But it has no effect at all, unfortunately. The problem is rather with the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` and `%{REQUEST_URI}` variables that obviously have different values in the subfolder and thus stop the rules from working correctly.